# Can I append data to the powerBI dataset rather than replace the whole dataset?

Tags: powerbi

I have 40 million rows in my dataset.  Each day I may get an extra 100 rows.  Obviously I don't want to have to import the whole 40 million each time I do a data refresh.  Is it possible to do an incremental refresh where only the new rows are added?

Comment: Why did you use Direct Query?

Comment: Vote for this: https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/7288623-incremental-data-loads

Comment: i didn't.  I'm importing the data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think incremental update as you describe it is possible yet.

It looks like you can [push rows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt203566.aspx) with Power BI REST API, if you're happy to switch to that.

<s>However, you might find this workaround useful:</s>

- Split your table and query into two: `where date <= 'somedate'` and `where date >'somedate'`
- Add an "empty query", use [`Table.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt260748) to join your two subtables. Use this as your main table.
- Whenever you need to refresh, only refresh the second query (the one with `where date >'somedate'`).
- Every once in a while, when that second query starts taking a long time, change `somedate` to the current date and do a full refresh.

Comment: Have you tried this or is this just a theory? I tried it but if I don't refresh combined table then nothing happens. If I refresh combined table then I didn't solve anything.

Answer (score 0):

The feature has now been implemented and is called Incremental refresh. Currently it is a premium only feature.